# How to show datepicker on page without calling on any even or just after page load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker for selecting a date but in the example [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)
 it is called on click into a text box. I just want the same right after page load. User should see the date picker right after the page load. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6h4gB/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker().focus();
});
```

---

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker().focus();
//attach date-picker to textbox and set focus on it
```

This code in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) so it runs after the document is loaded .

Answer (score 0):

Do it with javascript. 
On the pageload, call the method to display your date picker ;)